# The code does not produce the serial output

Tags: serial, arduino-zero

```c++
#include <Streaming.h>
#include <StopWatch.h>
#include <Albert.h>
#include "avdweb_AnalogReadFast.h"
const byte adcPin = A0;
void setup(void)
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while(!Serial);
    Serial << "\nanalogRead_10bit us1 analogRead_12bit us2 analogReadFast_10bit us3 analogReadFast_12bit us4";
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        testAnalogRead();
}
void testAnalogRead()
{
    static Stopwatch stopwatch(micros);
    //delay(1000);

    stopwatch.start();
    int adc1 = analogRead(adcPin); // default resolution 10bit 425us on SAMD21
    stopwatch.stop();
    int t1 = stopwatch.interval;

    analogReadResolution(12);
    stopwatch.start();
    int adc2 = analogRead(adcPin); // 425us on SAMD21
    stopwatch.stop();
    int t2 = stopwatch.interval;

    analogReadResolution(10);
    stopwatch.start();
    int adc3 = analogReadFast(adcPin); // 23us on SAMD21
    stopwatch.stop();
    int t3 = stopwatch.interval;

    analogReadResolution(12);
    stopwatch.start();
    int adc4 = analogReadFast(adcPin); // 24us on SAMD21
    stopwatch.stop();
    int t4 = stopwatch.interval;

    Serial << endl << adc1, t1, adc2, t2, adc3, t3, adc4, t4;
    analogReadResolution(10); // restore default
}
void loop()
{
}
```

This code does compile in the Arduino Zero, but does not produce the serial output on the serial monitor (serial plotter) at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please confirm, that the Arduino really executes the whole `setup()` function to the end, by turning on an LED at the end of the function? Maybe `Serial` cannot be initialized correctly, so that it stays in an infinite while loop. Also try a simple example sketch for serial communication to test, if this works

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. I was able to figure it out after spending few days. The main problem was the Albert.h library was not necessary for this code. I commented out # <Arduino.h> and this worked!!!